# Accessing SubClassed User Profile Module in Django 1.3

Tags: django, django-class-based-views, django-profiles

I am trying to create two user types in django 1.3. I am subclassing the AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE with the following models.py:

```
class Member(models.Model):
    ROLE_CHOICES = (
        (0, 'Guide'),
        (1, 'Operator'),
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    role = models.IntegerField(choices=ROLE_CHOICES)


class Guide(Member):
    bio = models.TextField(blank=True)
    experience = models.TextField(blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to='images')
    fileupload = models.FileField(blank=True, upload_to='files')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return '/profiles/guides/%s' % self.user.username


class Operator(Member):
    bio = models.TextField(blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to='images')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return '/profiles/operators/%s' % self.user.username
```

I am using generic class based views and can get the ListView to work for the Guide and Operator models I cannot get the DetailView to work. My views.py is as follows:

```
class GuideDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Guide
    context_object_name = 'guide'
    template_name = 'members/guide_detail.html'


class GuideListView(ListView):
    model = Guide
    context_object_name = 'guides'
    template_name = 'members/guide_list.html'
```

Any idea what  might be missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either provide a queryset:

```
class GuideDetailView(DetailView):
    queryset = Guide.objects.all()
```

or override the get Method of DetailView:

```
class GuideDetailView(DetailView):
    def get(self):
        return "Everything you want, maybe: Guide.object.get(id=1)"
```

Given this in your urls.py:

```
url(r'^(?P<my_id>\d)/$', GuideDetailView.as_view(),),
```

You need to override get, like this:

```
class GuideDetailView(DetailView):
    def get(self, request, **kwargs):
        # lookup Guide Id in your database and assign it object
        self.object = Guide.objects.get(pk=kwargs.get('my_id'))
        # add object to your context_data, so that you can access via your template
        context = self.get_context_data(object=self.object)
        return self.render_to_response(context)
```

Comment: I added the queryset = Guide.objects.all() as you suggested but still get an error that DetailView requires either a slug or pk. Any idea how I can utilize the username being passed in via the url for the slug value.

Comment: You have to add a argument in your urlconf, like: url(r'^$', GuideDetailView.as_view(), {'pk':1}),

Comment: I have edited my post, you should be able to solve your problem overriding the get method.

Comment: Thanks overriding the get method did it.